# I am facing this issue when I run flutter pub run build_runner build

Tags: flutter

[INFO] 28.9s elapsed, 4/5 actions completed.
[SEVERE] Unhandled build failure!
Invalid argument(s): name shouldn't end with a '.'
[SEVERE] Failed after 29.0s

I have tried solutions like flutter clean, flutter pub-cache repair flutter pub get and showing this error.

Comment: Please add full log

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.